# how to work with spinner to editview

Tags: android

**How to connect spinner to EditText**. In this regard, when we specify the input type through spinner that type of format enter in edittext.

*For Example*
**If spinner specify number type then we can only enter numbers in edittext** vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //this is your selected item
    switch(selectedItem){
    //set your edittext inputtype eg. edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
{

}           });
```